# make start block line point from right

Tags: python, printing, line, screen, pyside

```
lines = [
    "اهلا",
    "كيف حالك",
    "السطر الاول من الملف النصي",
    "السطر الثاني من الملف النصي",
    "السطر الثالث من الملف النصي",
    "السطر الرابع من الملف النصي",
    "السطر الخامس من الملف النصي",
    "السطر السادس من الملف النصي",
    "السطر السابع من الملف النصي"
]

for line in lines:
    print(line)
#its not sort the lines from right start
```

[image: output]

try to print each line start from right to left, without edit what inside line or how it display cuz that print words wrong, but make start printing point from right

Answer (score 0):

There are modules to reshape Arabic like `arabic_reshaper`. But, you just need to print your text from right to left.

You can use [str.rjust()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust)

```
lines = [ "اهلا", "كيف حالك", "السطر الاول من الملف النصي", "السطر الثاني من الملف النصي", "السطر الثالث من الملف النصي", "السطر الرابع من الملف النصي", "السطر الخامس من الملف النصي", "السطر السادس من الملف النصي", "السطر السابع من الملف النصي" ]
```

---

```
for x in lines:
  print(x.rjust(21, " "))
```

[image]